# Kivy button doesn't show

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am new to Kivy and just started to learn it today. However, I have already run into a problem on the very first steps: The button just won't show in the window.

.kv code

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
MainWidget:


<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        text: "Hello"
```

.py code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass

class TheLabApp(App):
    pass

TheLabApp().run()
```

I'm sorry that this is an absolute basic question, but I could not find anything online, that I could understand. As I am completely new to kivy, I got confused with similar errors with more advanced code.
The .kv and .py file are located in the same folder.

Comment: Make sure that the name of your `kv` file is `thelab.kv`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson This worked, thank you! I had it saved as "TheLab.kv" (upper case letters), as the tutor from the video did it that way, and it worked for him. Is this an older/newer version of kivy issue or what might be the problem?

Comment: Could be that the tutor is using `Windows`, which ignores case, and you are using some other OS.

Comment: He's on Mac, I am on Ubuntu, so that is probably it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Kivy looks for a Kv file with the same name as your App class in lowercase, minus “App” if it ends with ‘App’ e.g:`TheLabApp-> thelab.kv` so make sure your kivy filename is `thelab.kv`

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Make sure your kivy filename is "**thelab.kv**" instead of "**TheLab.kv**"
2. Add this line to your .py file -> `from kivy.uix.button import Button`

Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.